# What is the optimal volume when using external speakers with my Mac?

Tags: mac, audio, speakers

I was wondering whether there is an optimum volume I should set on my Mac when using an external pair of speakers. Should I set the Mac's volume to the max and then control volume with the knob on my speakers, or set the Mac's volume to some other value for optimum audio quality?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your external speakers from a speaker or headphone jack you probably want to avoid setting either volume control above ⅔ or ¾ to avoid clipping. If you are using a sound card you can set the internal volume at 100% and use the external control for volume adjustment.

Comment: Thanks penguirl, I'm using them through an iMic USB interface, so I assume that means I should go the soundcard route and set internal to 100?"